# Leak errors in valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I used in valgrind with my program and I got 2 errors :

```
==4909==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 3 blocks
==4909==   total heap usage: 41 allocs, 38 frees, 8,401 bytes allocated
==4909== 
==4909== 32 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==4909==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4909==    by 0x109CCE: addChar (Jerry.c:216)
==4909==    by 0x10AD57: main (MainFirst.c:128)
==4909== 
==4909== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==4909==    at 0x483DFAF: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4909==    by 0x109D98: addChar (Jerry.c:226)
==4909==    by 0x10AD57: main (MainFirst.c:128)
==4909== 
==4909== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4909==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 3 blocks
==4909==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4909==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4909==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4909==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4909== 
==4909== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The errors point to one function:

- The first in line 215 is the *malloc()* service;
- The second in line 225 is the *realloc()* service.

```
    int i=0;
    for (;i<countJerry;i++){
        if (strcmp(jerries[i].jerryID,j.jerryID)==0)
            break;
    }
    if (jerries[i].numOfChar==0)
    {
        jerries[i].jerryChar=(PhysicalCharacteristics*)malloc(sizeof(PhysicalCharacteristics));
        if (jerries[i].jerryChar==NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory Problem");
            freeMalloc();
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        jerries[i].jerryChar=(PhysicalCharacteristics*)realloc(jerries[i].jerryChar,(jerries[i].numOfChar+1)*sizeof(PhysicalCharacteristics));
        if (jerries[i].jerryChar==NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory Problem");
            freeMalloc();
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    jerries[i].jerryChar[jerries[i].numOfChar]=character;
    jerries[i].numOfChar++;
}
```

I can't find the problem. The original code is too long and I free all the *mallocs/reallocs* I created.

```
                    for (i=countJerry-1;i>=0;i--)
                    {
                    for (j=jerries[i].numOfChar-1;j>=0;j--)
                        free(jerries[i].jerryChar[j].nameChar);
                    free(jerries[i].jerryID);
                //  free(jerries[i].jerryChar);
                    }
                    free(jerries);
                    free(character);
                    for (i=countOrigins-1;i>=0;i--)
                        free(origins[i].nameO);
                    free(origins);
                    for(i=countPlanets-1;i>=0;i--)
                        free(planets[i].nameP);
                    free(planets);
```

So I can't find the problem.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code and other things that can be posted as text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Those aren't the "error lines". Those are were you allocated memory that wasn't freed. The error is the lack of freeing.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, when you use *realloc()*. When it returns **NULL** (i.e. when the free memory is exhausted), the original buffer is not freed. If you use the pointer on the original buffer, you loose the address of the buffer when *realloc()* returns NULL. The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) says:

> If realloc() fails, the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

So, it is preferable to use a temporary pointer to get the result of *realloc()*:

```c
PhysicalCharacteristics *tmp;
tmp=(PhysicalCharacteristics*)realloc(jerries[i].jerryChar, (jerries[i].numOfChar+1)*sizeof(PhysicalCharacteristics));
if (tmp==NULL) {
  printf("Memory Problem");
  freeMalloc();
  exit(1);
}
jerries[i].jerryChar = tmp;
```